# Interpolation methods: splines, kriging, IDW (Inverse Distance Weighting)

Tags: splines, interpolation

In general, do any one of these methods tend to out perform the others? I have been reading a paper in which it mentions that kriging tends to out perform splines but splines would never outperform kriging. I read another paper in which it says many times it is advantageous to use IDW over kriging - has a general consensus been reached? I assume it is possible to obtain kriging/IDW coefficients the same way one can obtain spline coefficients. Also, has anyone found a good definition for what the "Nugget Effect" is?

Comment: Do you mean *Kriging*?

Comment: Kriging was named for D.G. Krige and is so spelled (usually with lower case _k_ despite its origin).

Comment: References would help.

Comment: I suspect you might be reading some kind of GIS related paper; more specifically, something sponsored by or associated with ESRI. Be careful with such sources.  About 35 years ago or so it was established that many kinds of splines are an (automated) form of kriging, so the statement about splines is a little strange.  The algorithms for splines, IDW, and kriging differ substantially: maybe you should research those. Any authoritative account of kriging will explain the nugget effect.